# sbatch -time Not Setting Time Limit Correctly

Tags: slurm

I'm working on a large research cluster that has a default 30 minute timeout for any batch jobs submitted. I'm submitting my job with the line:

```
sbatch -p batch --job-name=$JOBNAME --time=1-00:00:00 --mail-type=ALL  --mail-user=[my email] --wrap="math -run \"<<scriptName.wl\""
```

but it still times out after 30 minutes? I'm just trying to set a 1-day time limit (which is much more than it should need), and I have no idea why this wouldn't be working.

Comment: The syntax looks correct ; and assuming you do not have warnings or errors during submission, I would check the output of `scontrol show job <JOBID>` and see what that says. Maybe if `$JOBNAME` is empty `--time=1-00:00:00`  is parsed the job name?

Comment: Does the partition you are running it on have a time limit? Take a look at `sinfo -l` or `sinfo -N -l`.

Comment: @damienfrancois had a good suggestion for troubleshooting. In my case, the OP command works correctly but seconds round up to the minute.